# Не работает программа вычисления значения интеграла по формуле трапеции

Tags: алгоритм, циклы, pascal, pascalabc.net, freepascal

было дано задание вычислить значение интеграла при помощи цикла с параметром, но программа на Pascal почему-то выдаёт неверный результат (0.11(6) вместо 0.183), ошибку у себя найти не могу. Был бы очень благодарен за помощь.

[image: скан задания]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Program lab3_3;
Var
  x, j, h, f, c: real;
  k: integer;
Const
  a = 1.5;
  b = 5;
  n = 30;
Begin
  Writeln('Введите параметр c:');
  Readln(c);
  h := (b - a) / n;
  f := 0;
  for k := 1 to n-1 do
  begin
    x := a + k*h;
    f := f + sin(x) / sqrt(c+x*x*x);
    writeln('x = ', x:8:5);
    writeln('f = ', f:8:5);
  end;
  j := h * trunc((sin(a) / sqrt(c+a*a*a) + sin(b) / sqrt(c+b*b*b))/2 + f);
  Writeln('Искомый интеграл = ', j)
End.
```

Comment: `trunc` - ?? *()*

Comment: @Igor , огромное спасибо! Действительно, без trunc() всё работает. В этом учебнике принято выражать целую часть при помощи квадратных скобок, а тут они оказались равносильны круглым :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
j := h * trunc((sin(a) / sqrt(c+a*a*a) + sin(b) / sqrt(c+b*b*b))/2 + f);
         ^^^^^
```

`trunc` не нужен.